# SQL Server : indexed varchar vs. nullable bit performance

Tags: sql-server

I designed a database with a nullable bit column to store test results of positive / negative / not tested, with pretty obvious correlation to 1/0/null. This seemed fine to me and I translate the values in the application and all is well.

My boss suddenly decided that this is not good and we should use a FK. I mentioned that avoiding extraneous FKs and tables is part of why I went with that, and he decided it would be better to use a `varchar` and store the whole domain value because "at least it's indexable" and "space is cheap".

Taking more space means taking more transfer time if you make decisions like that everywhere, but that aside, is there even a performance difference between an indexed `varchar` and a nullable `bit`? If there is I'd suspect the nullable bit would be faster, but I suspect others have more experience to say here than I.

Anyone weigh in on this? Is my boss correct on this?

If it matters, the software is in C# going through a WCF data service through EF to get to SQL Server.

Comment: Well, since space is cheap, whip up a sample table with a billion rows, make a bunch of indexes on it, and test it out. Benchmark the results and share with your boss. SQL Server provides the amount of reads, the execution plan, and the runtimes. Should be easy to gather objective metrics.

Comment: Also, write up a script that creates a table with a bit column, create a nonclustered index on it, and send it to your boss.

Comment: Also, in theory, your boss is right in that you should FK the column. Using your way, you are stuck with 3 possible values. What happens when the business comes back and wants to add a 4th indicator that means "flagged for review"? You are stuck and now have to refactor, add another column for this, or figure out something else.

Comment: Indexes in SQL Server are implemented as balanced trees. The performance of index lookups is detemined by the depth of the index tree. You can query the IndexDepth for your index with INDEXPROPERTY.

Then the question is if fewer index keys fit on a page with the proposed approach. That is something you can test. If so, you would also be able to test the index depth with the amount of data (range) you expect.